# What will decrease the performance of multithread except lock and the cost of thread's create and destory?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I wrote a program which use `std::thread::hardware_concurrency` to get how much threads my computer could support.Then I divide the size of array by N and get N blocks. And I create N threads to calculate the sum of the block.Here is the code

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>

int64_t thread_cost_time = 0;



template <typename Iterator, typename T> struct accumulate_block {
  void operator()(Iterator first, Iterator last, T &result) {
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    result = std::accumulate(first, last, result);
    
    auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto thread_time =
        std::chrono::duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start).count();
    thread_cost_time = std::max(thread_time, thread_cost_time);
  }
};

template <typename Iterator, typename T>
T parallel_accumulate(Iterator first, Iterator last, T &init, uint64_t num) {

  uint64_t length = std::distance(first, last);
  const uint64_t min_per_thread = 25;

  // it will assign 12 to hard_ware_threads in my pc
  const uint64_t hardware_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
  const uint64_t max_threads = (length + min_per_thread - 1) / (min_per_thread);

  // const uint64_t  num_threads = std::min(hardware_threads != 0 ?
  // hardware_threads : 2,
  //                                         max_threads);

  const uint64_t num_threads = num;

  const uint64_t block_size = length / num_threads;

  std::vector<T> results(num_threads);
  std::vector<std::thread> threads(num_threads - 1);
  Iterator block_start = first;
  for (uint64_t i = 0; i < num_threads - 1; i++) {
    Iterator block_end = block_start;
    std::advance(block_end, block_size);

    // calculate the sum of block
    threads[i] = std::thread{accumulate_block<Iterator, T>(), block_start,
                             block_end, std::ref(results[i])};
    block_start = block_end;
  }
  accumulate_block<Iterator, T>()(block_start, last, results[num_threads - 1]);
  std::for_each(threads.begin(), threads.end(),
                std::mem_fn(&std::thread::join));

  return std::accumulate(results.begin(), results.end(), init);
}




int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  //    constexpr const uint64_t sz = 1000000000;
  for (int number = 2; number < 32; number++) {
    int64_t parr = 0;
    int64_t single = 0;
    int64_t thread_trivial = 0;
    std::cout
        << "--------------------------------------------------------------"
        << std::endl;
    std::cout << "---------------------thread: " << number
              << "-----------------------" << std::endl;
    int iter_times = 10;
    for (int iter = 0; iter < iter_times; iter++) {
      thread_cost_time = 0;
      constexpr const uint64_t sz = 100000000 ;
      std::vector<uint64_t> arr;
      for (uint32_t i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        arr.emplace_back(i);
      }

      using namespace std::chrono;

      auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      uint64_t init = 0;
      parallel_accumulate<decltype(arr.begin()), uint64_t>(
                       arr.begin(), arr.end(), std::ref(init), number);
      auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

      parr += std::chrono::duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start).count();

      thread_trivial +=
          std::chrono::duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start).count() -
          thread_cost_time;
      uint64_t init_ = 0;
      uint64_t arr_sz = arr.size();
      // uint64_t  block_sz = arr.size() / 2;
      start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      std::accumulate(arr.begin(), arr.end(), init_);
      // std::cout << init_ << std::endl;
      stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      single += std::chrono::duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start).count();

    }
    std::cout << "parallel " << parr / iter_times<< std::endl;
    std::cout << "single thread " << single / iter_times<< std::endl;
    std::cout << "parr is "
              << static_cast<double>(single) / static_cast<double>(parr)
              << "X fast" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "thread create and destory time " << thread_trivial / iter_times
              << std::endl;
  }
}
```

I record the time of multithread and single thread.

#### I can only achieve at most 6.57x faster than use only one thread, even though `std::thread::hardware_concurrency` tell me I have 12 threads could run simultaneously.

There were no contention of lock in this program.I also record the time of create and destory the thread, even if I minus it , I still cannot achieve 12X faster.

I think maybe thread schedule will make multithreads slow, but I have 12 threads, It shouldn't achieve only 6.57x faster.
I think maybe multithreads will decrease the hit ratio of cache,but I'm not quite sure.
So how can I achieve 12X faster than use only one thread?

Here is my static of my program

| threads | parallel | single | faster |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 324868 | 633777 | 1.95 |
| 3 | 218584 | 633777 | 2.87 |
| 4 | 167169 | 633777 | 3.77 |
| 5 | 136542 | 633777 | 4.64 |
| 6 | 113207 | 633777 | 5.48 |
| 7 | 147324 | 633777 | 4.27 |
| 8 | 136768 | 633777 | 4.67 |

You could run my code to get the data from 2 threads to 31 threads

Comment: Memory access, cache size, OS scheduling .... You should never except 100% .

Comment: But I only achieve 50%, is it normal?

Comment: Context switches are also expensive.

Comment: Yes, but I have 12 threads could use, and it achieve only 4.27x faster when i use 7 threads

Comment: Have you tried [`std::reduce`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce) with [`std::execution::parallel_policy par`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag)? It's highly plausible the slowdown is in your code.

Comment: cache invalidation (aka ping ponging data between threads) is a real bottleneck. mono threaded application can be faster than multi threaded application if cache invalidation happens very frequently.

Comment: Also, the benchmark seems broken. Every benchmark should run alone. it could be that the multithreded version actually helps the mono threaded application, by, for example, help "seeding" malloc with free chucks that the mono threaded version might use later on with decreased effort.

Comment: @DavidHaim I run benchmark alone but it seems didn't change a lot ,could you tell me where I can get information about cache invalidation?

Comment: It's also worth noting that `int64_t thread_cost_time = 0;` is not thread safe as it is not `std::atomic_int64_t` and thus this creates a race condition. So the results are almost guaranteed to be off.

Comment: Do you really have 12 cores -- or is it 6 cores plus hyperthreading?

Comment: @Mgetz change it to ```std::atomic_int64_t```, didn't change a lot compare to int64_t

Comment: @tang it might not have, but it removed undefined behavior which could cause the compiler to optimize the benchmark incorrectly

Comment: @G.M. My cpu is i7-8700K, and ```lscpu``` tell me Cores per socket is 6 , and Threads per core is 2 , CPU is 12

Comment: @Mgetz thanks, i see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, at least on my Intel core i7, std::thread::hardware_concurrency() returns the number of hardware threads available. On hardware with simultaneous multi-threading typically 2 hardware threads share time on a single hardware core. The hardware core switches transparently between the 2 hardware threads. That means you only get about half the speedup factor that you might expect based on the result of std::thread::hardware_concurrency().

In practice each hardware thread will stall from time to time for various reasons, e.g. waiting for data to arrive from memory, giving the other hardware thread extra processing time. Typically simultaneous multi-threading (or  [Hyper-threading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading) as Intel calls it) will give you an extra 15% of performance that way, so you may expect a speedup factor of up to (12/2)*(115/100) = 6.9.

Overheads, including the one you mention, but also in my experience the increased working-set size, can further reduce the speed-up factor.